# ImageView Quality Not Smooth On Edges

Tags: android

I have an ImageView which I display on screen, the quality on the edges is not smooth, this is on emulator and on real device.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/temp_9" />
```

I have attached a picture to show the difference with the image on the left being from emulator (sharp edges) and the image on the right is the original PNG image (smooth edges).

- I have placed image in raw instead of drawable - not working
- I have moved the image across the different drawable folders - not working
- I have created a generic 'drawable' folder and placed image inside - not working
- I have created a 9 path image - not working
- I have reduced the image size using GIMP - not working
  [image]

Comment: this is the problem with emulators. on real device, it will be displayed fine.

Comment: @RahulKumar

Yes, too bad the first android device I tried the app on was an older model, on android 4.2+ (tested with 2 phones) the graphics are ok